# how to click on edit a button in front of Particular text in Cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress

[I want to click on the edit button in front of if found Yes in the third column(Yes is also have botton)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjD7R.png)

[element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNurV.png)

```
I was using below code in test case but didn't work
```

`cy.get(':nth-child(6)').contains('Yes').within(() => {
cy.get('.btn.btn-xs.btn-edit').click()
})
or

`cy.get(':nth-child(6)').contains('Yes').find(button).eq(1).click()

HTML Table Structure

```
    <tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="sorting_1">
<a href="http://192.168.0.1:8080/details">abc</a>
</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>aws</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>"Yes"
<button data-role="remove" id="support_22_abc" class="btn btn-rejecttxt" onclick="deletevm(this,'3','3:5659','22','abc','22_abc','284')"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" data-original-title="Remove Mapping" data-toggle="tooltip"></i></button></td>
<td>No</td>
<td>
<div class="btn-group">
<a href="http://192.168.0.1:8080/edit">
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-edit">
<i class="fa fa-pencil" data-original-title="Edit/Update row data" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"></i></button></a>
 </div></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.btn.btn-xs.btn-edit` is the correct selector for edit button. You can directly use the `eq` command to click the edit button on the third row.

```js
cy.get('.btn.btn-xs.btn-edit').eq(2).click()
```

Based on the available info, I came up with this. Here we are looping through the all the `tr` first and then using `within` we are scoping the next commands inside the same tr. Now using eq(5) we are searching for the `Yes` button, and if we found the it, then we click the Edit button.

```js
cy.get('tr').each(($ele) => {
  //Loop through all tr
  cy.wrap($ele).within(() => {
    //scope the next commands within the same tr
    cy.get('td')
      .eq(5)
      .invoke('text')
      .then((text) => {
        //here eq(5) gets the sixth td element in the row
        if (text.includes('Yes')) {
          cy.get('.btn.btn-xs.btn-edit').click()
        }
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: Hello Alapan There is a condition that if it find Yes in the column then click on edit button which is infront of Yes

Comment: I have to see the HTML of the entire table structure for this then.

Comment: added in question

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it correctly, you want the 3rd `<td>` after the one with "Yes ".

Not sure what `:nth-child(6)` is selecting, but try this

```js
cy.contains('td', 'Yes')
  .siblings()
  .eq(6)            // 6th sibling
  .find('button.btn.btn-xs.btn-edit')
  .click()
```

Comment: Thanks for update to HTML, I think these changes work.

Comment: Hi it works for me                                                                                    
   cy.contains('td', 'Yes')
  .siblings()
  .eq(6)            // 6th sibling
  .find('button.btn.btn-xs.btn-edit')
  .click()